# How to round my values with Math.ceil()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

got the following code:

```
var total = 0;
var $parent = $(this).closest('ul');

$parent.find('input:checked').each(function() {
  total += parseInt($(this).val() * parseInt(115, 10) / parseInt(100, 10) / parseInt(36, 10));
});

$parent.find('span[class^=total]').html(Math.ceil(total));
```

The code checks the value of my inputs and with parseInt i convert them to another value (its a fixed price converted to monthly costs over 3 years).

This works but the value which i output in my html at the end wont get rounded up:

So my question is, how i can round up the value of my html output.

Comment: The value of the total is in integer then how do you round it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `parseInt()` which will round down to the nearest int by default. If the original values are floating points you need to use `parseFloat()` instead.

```
$parent.find('input:checked').each(function() {
    total += parseFloat($(this).val()) * 115 / 100 / 36;
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/4ad447fq/)

Also note that you don't need to call `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` on literal integer values.

Comment: Thanks. Also for the tip with calling parseInt on integer values. Felt kinda clunky like i did. At first i tried it similar as you showed.. guess i made somewhere a mistake.